# Returning a named Tuple containing arrays

Tags: swift

In the following code, how do I get the return value to be addressable by name? Currently the return value has to be accessed with result.0 and result.1
I would like to be able to access them with result.beans and result.other

```
var groceryList = ["Baked Beans", "Green Beans", "Runner Beans", "Carrots", "Potatoes"]

func siftBeans(groceryList fromGroceryList: [String]) -> ([String],[String]){
    var newLists: (beans: [String], otherGroceries:[String]) = ([],[])
    for groceryItem in fromGroceryList {
        if groceryItem.hasSuffix("Beans") {
            newLists.beans.append(groceryItem)
        } else {
            newLists.otherGroceries.append(groceryItem)
        }
    }
    return (beans: newLists.beans, other: newLists.otherGroceries)
}
```

---

```
let result = siftBeans(groceryList: groceryList)
result.0
result.1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the names in the return type:

```
func siftBeans(groceryList fromGroceryList: [String]) 
    -> (beans: [String], other: [String]) {
    //  ^^^^^            ^^^^^

    // ...
}
```

To make your method shorter, you can make a type alias for this tuple type:

```
typealias SiftedBeans = (beans: [String], other: [String])
func siftBeans(groceryList fromGroceryList: [String]) -> SiftedBeans {
```